# No puedo obtener el valor de un Input en Javascript

Tags: javascript, html5

quiero obtener este valor de este input mediante la variable `entrada` pero al momento de mostrarlo me sale `null`. Este es mi codigo:

```
var entrada = document.getElementById('pagina');
    function url(){
        contenidoURL.innerHTML=`            
        <br>
        <center>Ingresa la URL de la pagina web que deseas analizar:<br><br>
              <input type="text" id="pagina" style=" width: 50%;"  class="form-control"><br>
              <button type="submit" onclick="analizaURL()" class="btn btn-warning">Analizar</button>
        </center><br><br>`
    }

    function pagina(){
    alert(entrada);
    }
```

¿Cómo puedo arreglarlo? Gracias

Answer (score 2):

Cuando estas declarando la variable entrada y obteniendo el elemento, posiblemente no este todavía definido el elemento en si.

Tendras que esperar a que este para poder obtenerlo, como veo que el elemento se crea en la función `url` una forma seria la siguiente:

```
var entrada = null;
    function url(){
        contenidoURL.innerHTML=`            
        <br>
        <center>Ingresa la URL de la pagina web que deseas analizar:<br><br>
              <input type="text" id="pagina" style=" width: 50%;"  class="form-control"><br>
              <button type="submit" onclick="analizaURL()" class="btn btn-warning">Analizar</button>
        </center><br><br>`

       entrada = document.getElementById('pagina');
    }

    function pagina(){
    alert(entrada.value);
    }
```

Comment: Me regresa un ObjectHTMLInputElement

Comment: Perdon, pense que querias el objeto, te modifico la respuesta para obtener el valor.

Comment: Muchas gracias!